# How to convert a List<T> into a Dictionary<> using a T property as key and rest of properties as List<T1>

Tags: c#, linq, list, properties, dictionary

I have a `Product` class:

```
class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime ProductionDate { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
}
```

If I have a `List<Product>` and I want to `GroupBy` by `ProductionDate` and `CategoryId`. I do:

```
List<Product> products = GetAllProducts();

var groupedProducts = products.Groupby(p => new { p.ProductionDate, p.CategoryId })
                              .Select(pgroup => new {
                                                  prodDate = pgroup.Key.ProductionDate.ToString(),
                                                  categoryId = pgroup.Key.CategoryId.ToString(),
                                                  amount = pgroup.Count() 
                                                });
```

For each `categoryId` I would like to have how many `products` have been produced in a specific `prodDate`. So I create a `Dictionary` object where for each `categoryId` key, I store the `prodDate` and the `amount`. The object is a `Dictionary<string, List<Data>>` with

```
class Data
{
     public string xValue { get; set; }
     public string yValue { get; set; }
}
```

To do so I tried:

```
Dictionary<string, List<Data>> productsPerPeriodPerCategory = new Dictionary<string, List<Data>>();
productsPerPeriodPerCategory = groupedProducts
                               .ToDictionary(p => p.categoryId, 
                                             p => new List<Data>().AddRange(
                                                  groupedProducts.Where(g => g.categoryId == p.categoryId)
                                                                 .Select(x => new Data()
                                                                    {
                                                                       xValue = x.prodDate,
                                                                       yValue = x.amount.ToString()
                                                                    }).ToList()));
```

But it gives me the following error:

```
Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<string>' because it is not a delegate type
```

Comment: Two questions.  1) What forms `groupedProducts`?  If your `GroupBy` is correct, you shouldn't need `.Where(g => g.categoryId == p.categoryId)`.  2) Why are you calling `ToList()` on your items, then adding that List to a new List.  That seems redundant.

Comment: 1) *g.categoryId == p.categoryId*, if you see they are at a different scope level. *p.categoryId* is in a higher scope it stay fixed, while *g.categoryId* "cycles" over the collection. The *GroupBy* is made on multiple columns, therefore given a fixed *prodDate* there can be different *categoryId* 2) Yes you are right but if I remove it I don't solve much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
productsPerPeriodPerCategory =
        groupedProducts
            .GroupBy(p => p.categoryId)
            .ToDictionary(
                g => g.Key,
                g =>
                g.Select(
                    r =>
                    new Data {xValue = r.prodDate, yValue = r.amount.ToString()}));
```

Comment: Your solution works thanks. However may you explain to me the reasoning underneath the Select? It gets all the record that have the same key of the groupby?

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that `AddRange` does not return the list, and you've already grouped so no need for the `Where`.

This should suffice:

```
productsPerPeriodPerCategory = groupedProducts
           .ToDictionary(p => p.categoryId, 
                         p => p.Select(x =>  new Data()
                                             {
                                                 xValue = x.prodDate,
                                                 yValue = x.amount.ToString()
                                             }).ToList());
```

You could also do this all in 1 step if you dont need the intermediate group

```
List<Product> products = GetAllProducts();
var groupedProducts = products.Groupby(p => new { p.ProductionDate, p.CategoryId })  
                          .ToDictionary(
                               x => x.Key.CategoryId,
                               x => new Data()
                                     { 
                                         xValue = x.Key.ProductionDate.ToString(),
                                         yValue = x.Count().ToString()
                                     });
```

Comment: Thanks! But 'AnonymousType#1' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'AnonymousType#1' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?). In the p.Select of your first code

Comment: @Jamiec  You can get `ArgumentException "An element with the same key already exists in the Dictionary<TKey, TValue>"` in `ToDictionary(x => x.Key.CategoryId,...`